# iAds with swift in table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

hi can u help me i want to iAdd in my scroll view controller but and i add it but it show on top of my table :( in swift

this is my code

```
var dataModel: DataModel!
var bannerView = ADBannerView()    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rowHeight = 60
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    //Rate my apps alert codes
    var iMinSessions = 20
    var iTryAgainSessions = 30
    var iNoThanks = 50

    var thanksforrate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("thanksforrate")
    var neverRate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("neverRate")
    var numLaunches = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("numLaunches") + 1

    if (!neverRate && (numLaunches == iMinSessions || numLaunches >= (iMinSessions + iTryAgainSessions + iNoThanks + 1)))
    {
        showRateMe()
        numLaunches = iMinSessions + 1
        numLaunches = iNoThanks + 1
    }
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(numLaunches, forKey: "numLaunches")

    //BannerView

    bannerView = ADBannerView(adType: .Banner)
    bannerView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    bannerView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(bannerView)

    let viewsDictionary = \["bannerView": bannerView\]

    //view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|\[bannerView\]", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    //view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|\[bannerView\]", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))

}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    bannerView.hidden = false
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    bannerView.hidden = true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 50
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    var adView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50))
    adView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth

    bannerView = ADBannerView(adType: .Banner)
    bannerView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    bannerView.delegate = self
    adView.addSubview(self.bannerView!)

    return adView
}
```

Comment: now time to upload my apps in app store should i need any other code for upload my apps in app store thanks

Comment: I think that's it you done everting to setup iAD.But you need to configure licence agreement in iTunesConnect.check this link which give information about how to setup licence agreement http://codewithchris.com/iad-tutorial/. You can check you add status in iADworkbench.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in viewDidLoad

```
  self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top:self.bannerView.frame.size.height, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: its crash fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: after i delete this two lines its works but //let viewsDictionary = ["bannerView": bannerView]
        
        //view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[bannerView]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
its show now in 2nd row from up i need put this in last down in my apps

Comment: Try to add banner in either header or footer view of tableView.

Comment: i want in footer but i can do it help me